# How to use Countifs with multiple conditions in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell, countif

I'm working on a macro that counts data with multiple conditions from a database.

There is a column that corresponds to the shift schedule of workers and another that indicates the production line to which they belong.

I tried to use the Countifs function

```
Sheet1.Cells(2, 3) = Application.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range(Cells(2, 3), _
      Cells(7, 3)), "7M08", Sheet2.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(7, 4)), "4")
```

I try to find the work shift "7M08" between row 2 and 7 of column 3. It must also happen that the line of production sought between row 2 and 7 of column 4 is equal to 4.

Currently there is an error in the Range method, but it is for me necessary to look for the cells in the way Cells (1,2) instead of B1.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
Dim Rng As Range

With Sheet2
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(7, 3))
End With
Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value = Application.CountIfs(Rng, "7M08", Rng.Offset(0, 1), "4")
```

Comment: Hi, what Rng.Offset(0, 1) do?

Comment: Try: `? Range("C2:C7").Offset(0, 1).Address` pasted to the Immediate Window. The result will be $D$2:$D$7, meaning, the original address removed one column to the right.

Comment: I have a vba error in the last line: Wrong number of arguments.

Comment: You must have an extra comma in your formula. Try your formula on a worksheet, replacing the two ranges with actual addresses. Try it in VBA by removing one pair of Range & criteria.